# How do I printout multiple text in JText Field using if/else statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, jtextfield

[image]

```
    private void resultActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if(pick1 > pick2 ){
    resultstf.setText("The New President is Koon!");
    }
    else if(pick2 > pick1){
    resultstf.setText("The New President is Baam!");
    }
    else if(pick1 == pick2){
    resultstf.setText("The Result for the new President is a Tie! Please Vote Again.");
    }
    if(pick3 > pick4){
    resultstf.setText("The New VP is Sachi!");
    }
    else if(pick4 > pick3){
    resultstf.setText("The New VP is Faker!");
    }
}
```

How do I print out multiple Text whenever I press the Result Button? Like I want to print out "The New President is Koon" and also printout "The New VP is Sachi" at the same time.

Comment: you could have searched a bit more online - Use of  `StringBuilder` will do the needful check the answer as well as the question - http://stackoverflow.com/a/15383945/6426617

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `StringBuilder` and build the message as you go along:

```
private void resultActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();                                   
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    if (pick1 > pick2) {
        message.append("The New President is Koon!\n");
    }
    else if (pick2 > pick1) {
        message.append("The New President is Baam!\n");
    }
    else if (pick1 == pick2) {
        message.append("The Result for the new President is a Tie! Please Vote Again.\n");
    }
    if (pick3 > pick4) {
        message.append("The New VP is Sachi!\n");
    }
    else if (pick4 > pick3) {
        message.append("The New VP is Faker!\n");
    }

    resultstf.setText(message.toString());
}
```